# python request wrong html when used get function

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to consume data from [this](http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?m=4) site and save into database. When I view the site using firebug, the table row are well formed. But my following code gets the wrong `html` content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib2
from peewee import SqliteDatabase,CharField,Model

db = SqliteDatabase("cybercrime.db")
class CyberCrimeList(Model):
    date = CharField()
    url = CharField()
    ip = CharField()
    type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


url = "http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?m=4"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table',attrs={'class':'ExploitTable'})
print table.tbody
```

But the code only gives first row which is incorrectly formatted. I get `</tr></td>` instead of `</td></tr>`.

Is there something I am misssing? What's wrong in my code?

```
<tr><td>23-11-2015</td>
<td>jda3.byethost3.com/panel/index.php?login</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/185.27.134.160/information/" target="_blank">185.27.134.160</a></td>
<td>Solar</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/latest-scan/http://jda3.byethost3.com/panel/index.php?login" target="_blank"><img alt="Scan with VirusTotal" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Scan with VirusTotal" src="vt.png" width="13"/></a> <a href="http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?s=0&amp;m=40&amp;search=Solar"><img alt="Search the family" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Search the family" src="vwicn008.gif" width="13"/></a></td></tr>
```

Comment: So what do you want to get?

Comment: I will be filling database with value of date, url, ip and type. But for now, the code only gives one row instead of four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lxml` to get all results

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

it seems that `"html.parser"` has a problem with this html.

Comment: Using `lxml` seems to fix the problem. `html.parser` as the doc says `Not very lenient`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try search the `tr` tag like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib2
from peewee import SqliteDatabase,CharField,Model

db = SqliteDatabase("cybercrime.db")
class CyberCrimeList(Model):
    date = CharField()
    url = CharField()
    ip = CharField()
    type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

url = "http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?m=4"
response = requests.get(url)

html = response.text  
# I'd recommend use r.text instead r.content if the results is text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")       
tables = soup.find_all('tr')

for table in tables[1:]:  # skip the first element
    print(table)
    print()
```

The output looks like:

```
<tr><td>23-11-2015</td>
<td>jda3.byethost3.com/panel/index.php?login</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/185.27.134.160/information/" target="_blank">185.27.134.160</a></td>
<td>Solar</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/latest-scan/http://jda3.byethost3.com/panel/index.php?login" target="_blank"><img alt="Scan with VirusTotal" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Scan with VirusTotal" src="vt.png" width="13"/></a> <a href="http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?s=0&amp;m=40&amp;search=Solar"><img alt="Search the family" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Search the family" src="vwicn008.gif" width="13"/></a></td></tr>

<tr><td>23-11-2015</td>
<td>www.fyzee.top/senikan/web/login.php</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/68.168.209.242/information/" target="_blank">68.168.209.242</a></td>
<td>KeyBase</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/latest-scan/http://www.fyzee.top/senikan/web/login.php" target="_blank"><img alt="Scan with VirusTotal" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Scan with VirusTotal" src="vt.png" width="13"/></a> <a href="http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?s=0&amp;m=40&amp;search=KeyBase"><img alt="Search the family" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Search the family" src="vwicn008.gif" width="13"/></a></td></tr>

<tr><td>23-11-2015</td>
<td>www.fyzee.top/kech/web/login.php</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/68.168.209.242/information/" target="_blank">68.168.209.242</a></td>
<td>KeyBase</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/latest-scan/http://www.fyzee.top/kech/web/login.php" target="_blank"><img alt="Scan with VirusTotal" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Scan with VirusTotal" src="vt.png" width="13"/></a> <a href="http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?s=0&amp;m=40&amp;search=KeyBase"><img alt="Search the family" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Search the family" src="vwicn008.gif" width="13"/></a></td></tr>

<tr><td>23-11-2015</td>
<td>sentfactor.com/medinshushu/admin.php</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/50.31.160.159/information/" target="_blank">50.31.160.159</a></td>
<td>Pony</td>
<td><a href="https://www.virustotal.com/latest-scan/http://sentfactor.com/medinshushu/admin.php" target="_blank"><img alt="Scan with VirusTotal" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Scan with VirusTotal" src="vt.png" width="13"/></a> <a href="http://cybercrime-tracker.net/index.php?s=0&amp;m=40&amp;search=Pony"><img alt="Search the family" border="0" height="12" longdesc="Search the family" src="vwicn008.gif" width="13"/></a></td></tr>
```